# How to differentiate a connection error from 404 in Spring RestTempate?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using spring `RestTempate` for get queries.

```
try {
    restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, headers, MyDto.class);
} catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
    //this is thrown both on invalid url path, and on a servers 404 response
    //both contain e.statusCode == 404
}
```

Problem: a 404 looks the same as an invalid url (eg if the webservice servlet I'm connecting to is not deployed, but the server is up in general, which also gives a 404).

The server itself is a `REST` webservice, and when I request `/person/12` and person with `id=12` does not exist, the server also responds with `404`.

Question: how can I differentiate between correct 404, and 404 due to url/path errors?

Comment: I would say you simply can't unless the REST API tells you something more about it. I know implementations that send a 404 _and_ give you a "not found" in a JSON. Everything else would involve "probing", in your scenario you could check for `/person/`. But I think your problem is only academical.

Comment: Do you have control in the server code to which you are connecting via restTemplate? If you do, you can configure the server to return a custom error message for invalid url which is can easily be done in spring MVC.

Comment: I don't have server control. My workaround is not to read the `Content-Length` header, which is empty for not found persons, and > 0 for tomcat error message.

Comment: So you identified the Content-Length as a means to detect which of both 404s happened.

Comment: Exactly that is. (sidenote: I ment to write "is now to read", not "is not to read".